# What is a Less file?

Tags: html, css

I've started working newly on the [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(web_framework)) library. In the entire codebase that I've to work upon, I see `*.less` files which contain classes related to styles just as we used to have in CSS files for HTML/JavaScript pages.

How is a .less file any different from the conventional CSS style sheets? Can we also use `*.css` files with `*.JSX` files for styling purposes?

Comment: http://lesscss.org/ Css preprocessor

Comment: Less allows you to write CSS more elegantly. Less is a superset of standard CSS so renaming them to `*.css` will probably break them.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[Less](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_%28stylesheet_language%29) is basically a CSS-like language with additional capabilities that can be compiled to CSS using a preprocessor.

Examples of these additional capabilities are:

Variable definition. Suppose you have a color scheme to follow on your web site/application and need to keep reusing that same color, you can store that color in a variable and keep using it everywhere (instead of having to remember the hexadecimal code say).

```
    @nice-blue: #5B83AD;

    #header {
      color: @nice-blue;
    }
```

Suppose later you want to change the color, you can simply change the variable instead of going through all the CSS and changing the manually.

There are also other neat stuff like loops, etc. You can check [their documentation](http://lesscss.org/) for more information.

Another popular preprocessor you can check out is [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/).

Comment: Adding to above : LESS is JavaScript based and Sass is Ruby based